# Regex with Hyphen-separated Content

Tags: java, regex

How would I strip this email address?

t-i-f-f-@-y-a-h-o-o-.-c-o-m

I basically need to ignore every hyphen; what I have written is as follows:

```
(?:[\\w\\.]-?)+)@-((?:[\\w\\.]-?)+)\\.-((?:[\\w\\.]-?){3})
```

The above is not recognizing anything though..

Without the hyphens, I know the following code works:

```
([\\w\\.]+)@([\\w\\.]+).([\\w]{3})
```

Comment: why not just remove all `'-'` before matching?

Comment: Or match everything that is not a `-`? With: `[^-]+`

Comment: Regex is not proper `(?: [\w\.] -? )+  )  <-- Unbalanced  ')'`

Answer (score 0):

This just matches it, you might need to strip '-' separetly

```
 #  "(?:-*[\\w.])+-*@(?:-*[\\w.])+-*\\.(?:-*[\\w]){3}"

 (?: -* [\w.] )+
 -* @  
 (?: -* [\w.] )+
 -* \. 
 (?: -* [\w]  ){3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the hyphens with [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

```
String strippedEmail = email.replace("-", "");
```